# Adding a server to the database when inviting a discord server botan

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to make it so that, when adding a bot to the server, it adds to the mongoose database the server on which the bot entered.

Column code for the database:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const PrefixSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    Prefix: { type: String, default: "!"},
    GuildID: { type: String },
    Locale: { type: String, default: "en" },

});

const MessageModel = module.exports = mongoose.model('guild-stitch', PrefixSchema);
```

This is necessary in order for me to work changing the language in the bat otherwise the bot simply does not work.

As I understand it, I need to add something to index.js, but I don't know what exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I do in my production bots is firstly check if the settings already exist for the server to avoid duplicate documents/unexpected errors. Since you haven't really specified too much I will be assuming you're using `discord.js` with the `guildCreate` event and that you have already defined the schema.

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// There is also another way to get the schema, but since you haven't provided much information I have simply fetched it the 'global' way.
const PrefixSchema = mongoose.model('guild-stich').schema;

// Also assuming you already have a client defined.
client.on('guildCreate', async guild => {
   // First fetch the settings.
   let settings = await PrefixSchema.findOne({ GuildID: guild.id }).exec();

   // If does not exist, create and let defaults handle the rest.
   if (!settings) settings = await (new PrefixSchema({ GuildID: guild.id })).save();
   
   // At this point you can be certain the settings for this guild exist.
   // I structured my solution in a way that you have access to the settings object for that guild, even if it didn't previously exist.

   // For example:
   console.log(`${settings.GuildID}: ${settings.Prefix}`);
});
```

You can use this to implement this in your code from my example.